# chrome extension manifest v2 : jquery not loaded

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome

i'm currently making a chrome extension that sends cross domain POST request to my server.Basicly I can right click on an image and have the option to send the image url to
my server via json.

The files :

```
manifest.json
background.html
callback.js
jquey.min.js
icon48.png
```

Here is the source :

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "POST image",
  "description": "Post image to my server",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "http://example.org/*" ],
  "background": { "page": "background.html" },
  "browser_action": { "default_icon": "icon48.png", "default_title": "POST image" },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="callback.js"></script>
```

callback.js

```
function sendnow(imgurl) {
    var imageurl = imgurl.srcUrl;
    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.org/images.php?action=add&jsoncallback=?",
        type: "POST",
        data: { post_key: "7xdnu3", post_data: imageurl },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            switch (result) {
                case true:
                    processResponse(result);
                    break;
                default:
                    resultDiv.html(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("failed.");
        }
    });
alert('Image "'+imageurl+'" sent');
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Send to my server", contexts:["image"], onclick: sendnow});
```

I guess callback.js runs as expected because i was able to do the right click on an image and see the option "Send to my server".I got the alert prompt as expected but the the data is not sent properly because i can't see it on my server.

**Update** : Everything is fine on the server end and the script works properly when i placed it directly in a html file(inline).Seems like it doesn't work when placed in a javascript file which is what the manifest v2 wants.